# Using conditions in ROS2 command line

Tags: ros2

I had a ROS2 project that could run in two flavours: slam and map:

```
slam = LaunchConfiguration('slam')
#slam = LaunchConfigurationEquals('mode', 'slam')
declare_slam_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'slam',
    default_value='True',
    description='Whether run a SLAM')
arrNodes.append(declare_slam_cmd)

...

    bringup_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(def_launch_dir, 'bringup_launch.py')),
        #condition=LaunchConfigurationNotEquals('mode', 'simple'),
        launch_arguments={
            'namespace': robot['name'],
            'use_namespace': 'True',
            'slam': slam,
            'map': map_yaml_file,
            'keepout_mask': keepout_mask,
            'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
            'params_file': params_file,
            'default_bt_xml_filename': default_bt_xml_filename,
            'autostart': 'True' }.items())
    bringup_timer_action = launch.actions.TimerAction( period=5.0, actions=[ bringup_cmd ])
    arrNodes.append(bringup_timer_action)
```

Now I want to add the third flavor (simple, slam, map), so the condition is no longer binary. I want to remove binary "slam" parameter and add "mode" which will have one of "simple, slam, map" values.

I tried If/Unless and LaunchConfigurationNotEquals - no success.

An additional problem is in "bringup" script, which takes "slam" boolean, so I need to derive this parameter from "mode": if mode not equal "slam", then False, else True.

Any suggestions appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Uhm, the tag says "Please ask ROS 2 related questions on https://robotics.stackexchange.com from now on."

Comment: Missed that. Where is it?

Comment: When you hover your mouse pointer over the added tag.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can create "slam" parameter, rather than passing it (complete code at [enter link description here](https://robotics.snowcron.com), in "multiple robots" section):

```
# simple, slam, map
mode = LaunchConfiguration('mode')
declare_mode_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'mode',
    default_value='simple',
    description='Whether run robot in a simple mode, SLAM or Map')
arrNodes.append(declare_mode_cmd)

#slam = LaunchConfiguration('slam')
slam = PythonExpression(["'", mode, "'=='slam'"]) 
declare_slam_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'slam',
    default_value='True',
    description='Whether run a SLAM')
arrNodes.append(declare_slam_cmd)
```

Then I can use both "node" and "slam":

```
bringup_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(def_launch_dir, 'bringup_launch.py')),
    condition=LaunchConfigurationNotEquals('mode', 'simple'),
    launch_arguments={
        'namespace': robot['name'],
        'use_namespace': 'True',
        'slam': slam,
        'map': map_yaml_file,
        'keepout_mask': keepout_mask,
        'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
        'params_file': params_file,
        'default_bt_xml_filename': default_bt_xml_filename,
        'autostart': 'True' }.items())
bringup_timer_action = launch.actions.TimerAction( period=5.0, actions=[ bringup_cmd ])
```